# Error when trying to deploy react.js app to heruko

Tags: reactjs, heroku, npm, deployment, yarnpkg

Okay, so I need to deploy my react.js application to heroku, but it keeps giving me an error.

The application uses yarn instead of npm. The application builds on top of fuse React template. I've specified the engines in the package.json as yarn and node, but it keeps giving me an error. See the code below to get a deeper understanding.

This is my package.json file

```
{
"name": "fuse-react-app",
"version": "3.1.0",
"private": true,
"engines": {
    "yarn": "1.15.2",
    "node": "10.16.0"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@date-io/date-fns": "1.3.7",
    "@material-ui/core": "4.1.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "4.2.1",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "3.1.2",
    "@material-ui/styles": "4.1.2",
    "auth0-lock": "11.16.3",
    "autosuggest-highlight": "3.1.1",
    "axios": "0.19.0",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "1.16.0",
    "chart.js": "2.8.0",
    "date-fns": "2.0.0-beta.1",
    "downshift": "3.2.10",
    "firebase": "6.2.3",
    "formsy-react": "1.1.5",
    "google-map-react": "1.1.4",
    "jsonwebtoken": "8.5.1",
    "jss": "10.0.0-alpha.21",
    "jss-extend": "6.2.0",
    "jwt-decode": "2.2.0",
    "keycode": "2.2.0",
    "lodash": "4.17.11",
    "material-table": "1.40.0",
    "material-ui-popup-state": "1.4.0",
    "mobile-detect": "1.4.3",
    "moment": "2.24.0",
    "notistack": "0.8.7",
    "path-to-regexp": "3.0.0",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "1.4.0",
    "prismjs": "1.16.0",
    "qs": "6.7.0",
    "raw-loader": "1.0.0",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-autosuggest": "9.4.3",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "11.0.4",
    "react-big-calendar": "0.22.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "2.7.6",
    "react-dom": "16.8.6",
    "react-draggable": "3.3.0",
    "react-frame-component": "4.1.0",
    "react-masonry-css": "1.0.12",
    "react-number-format": "4.0.8",
    "react-popper": "1.3.3",
    "react-redux": "7.1.0",
    "react-router-config": "5.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "5.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
    "react-select": "2.4.4",
    "react-swipeable-views": "0.13.3",
    "react-table": "6.10.0",
    "react-text-mask": "5.4.3",
    "react-virtualized": "9.21.1",
    "react-window": "1.8.3",
    "redux": "4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "2.3.0",
    "typeface-muli": "0.0.71",
    "velocity-react": "1.4.3"
},
"resolutions": {
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "16.8.6"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.4.5",
    "@babel/node": "7.4.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.4.5",
    "cross-env": "5.2.0",
    "globby": "9.2.0",
    "js-beautify": "1.10.0",
    "marked": "0.6.2",
    "purgecss": "1.3.0",
    "tailwindcss": "1.0.4",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "3.3.2"
},
"scripts": {
    "start": "yarn run tailwind && react-scripts start",
    "build": "yarn run tailwind && node ./purge-tailwindcss.js && cross-env GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build",
    "tailwind": "./node_modules/.bin/tailwind build ./src/styles/tailwind.base.css -c ./tailwind.js -o ./src/styles/tailwind.css",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=node",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "build-docs": "find ./src/app/main/documentation/material-ui-components \\( -name '*.ts' -o -name '*.tsx' \\) -type f -delete && babel-node src/app/main/documentation/material-ui-components/build.js",
    "build-stats": "yarn run build --stats",
    "bundle-report": "yarn run build-stats && webpack-bundle-analyzer build/bundle-stats.json -m static -r build/bundle-stats.html -O"
},
"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
},
"browserslist": {
    "production": [
        ">0.2%",
        "not dead",
        "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
        "last 1 chrome version",
        "last 1 firefox version",
        "last 1 safari version",
        "ie 11"
    ]
 }
}
```

This is the error I get on heroku:

> 2019-07-08T11:25:56.852293+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
>   2019-07-08T11:25:56.852517+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
>   2019-07-08T11:25:56.852647+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the fuse-react-app@3.1.0 start script.
>   2019-07-08T11:25:56.852779+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>   2019-07-08T11:25:56.860485+00:00 app[web.1]: 
>   2019-07-08T11:25:56.860724+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   2019-07-08T11:25:56.860877+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-07-08T11_25_56_854Z-debug.log
>   2019-07-08T11:25:56.921581+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1

It says that it's trying to run npm. But the application doesnt use npm.. Hope you guys can help me..

Comment: Hi, did my answer make sense? Were you able to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

In order to deploy the fuse-react template to heroku you need to complete a couple extra steps to ensure your developer dependencies are properly installed.

Directly from their provided `Readme.txt` file, here are the necessary steps:

### HEROKU NOTES

You may encounter issues if you want to *deploy fuse-react to heroku*, here is the solution:

1. Disable production mode to install devDependencies:

   `heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false`
2. Push your branch to the master branch on Heroku:

   `git push heroku <branch>:master`

Hopefully that helps!